# var.before('<br>'); returns "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to use the function `.before()` in order to separate some inputs generated by a `for-loop`. To make it work, I have to use a variable as a reference to know where to insert the `<br>`. The problem is it returns `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and I can't find any documentation that would prevent me to do it like I do.

Here's the code:

```
<textarea id="textareaString">0|1|2|3</textarea>
<br />
<button onClick="cut()">Cut!</button>
<div id="specials"></div>


function cut() {
    var str = document.getElementById('textareaString').value;
    var arrayOfStrings = str.split('|');
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++)  {
        var legend = document.getElementById('specials');
        var mo = document.createElement('input');
        mo.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        mo.setAttribute('size', '5');
        mo.setAttribute('id', 'special' + (i+1));
        mo.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings[i]);
        legend.appendChild(mo);
    }
    console.log(arrayOfStrings);
    arrayOfStrings.before('<br /><br />');
}
```

According to the problematic line is the last one: `arrayOfStrings.before('<br /><br />');`

You can play it [on this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0hjx2ob/). Please take into account the fact I've cut a lot of code here, and I can't consider using the `id` of the input to use as reference for `.before()`, it would work here but not with the full code. If you want to check it out, it's [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uavgrac2/) (in this one I need to add a 
 after each cut using `|`).

What am I missing exactly? That may be stupid, but I just can't find it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: legend.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

Comment: Which "function `.before()`"? There is no function `.before()`! Please show me the documentation which tells you could use one.

Comment: That's actually a jQuery function: http://api.jquery.com/before/ Anyway, @dandavis gave me a perfect working answer, thank you! If you wanna do a real reply so I can accept it :) Updated JSFiddle 1:  http://jsfiddle.net/s0hjx2ob/1, updated JSFiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/uavgrac2/2/

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to use [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) from JQuery

Since you are not working with a jQuery object, .before won't be accesible to you.

Also, you can take `var legend = document.getElementById('specials');` out of your loop.

If `'<br /><br />'` is a text in your array, you can do `arrayOfStrings.indexOf('<br /><br />')` to locate the position of your string, and then use `.slice` to get the part you are searching for.

Comment: Okay I see, thanks for the explanation! I've put the var out of the loop. The <br> are not part of the array, but @dandavis actually found a very good workaround.